# How to download xls file generated by the Jasper Report in extj 4.0.2a

Tags: java, hibernate, extjs

Hello stackoverflow forum member. I need some support from you to generate the excel report and then download it with one click.

I am working on extjs 4.0.2a along with Java. In java framework such as Hibernate/JPA and Spring. I am using Jasper Report to generate the report in excel and pdf. I am able to generate the report using it. But the problem is that I am not able to download it in my browser. Also my browser didn't prompt me to save or cancel the report generated.

I am making request to server to generate the excel report using:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({url:'task/GetTaskReportXLS.action',   
   success:function(response,option){console.log("success");},
failure:function(response,option){console.log("failure");},
scope:this});
```

On my server side I am generating the excel report with response parameter as

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=\"gantt.xls\"");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
```

When I click the export button the process executes and as the response on my firebug console I am getting headers as:

```
Response Headers
Content-Disposition attachment
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    application/vnd.ms-excel
Date    Fri, 20 Jan 2012 10:00:49 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

But still my download prompt not appear to save my excel report. Help me to point out what things I am doing wrong here.

I am using extjs 4.0.2a mvc architecture with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get your file because of your success function. You only write log and don't do anything with response. 
Try 
    window.open('task/GetTaskReportXLS.action')

Comment: thanks Vadim for you response but it didn't work. And the same things happen when i generate the report in pdf.